# Function doesn't update 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2D list P[30][30] that indicates probabilities. I have set the values of the list as 0 and i want to update them. I have created a function to update the values of the list I want but they still remain 0.

```
def Prop(graph,i,candidate_nodes,Pr,t,n1):
    pp=0

    for j in candidate_nodes:
        pp+=(t[i][j]*n1[i][j])
    for k in candidate_nodes:
        Pr[i][k]=(t[i][k]*n1[i][k])/pp

     return Pr
```

Comment: what does candidate_nodes contain?

Comment: [ask]... [mcve]...

Comment: ints that represent points. Also, i printed Pr[i][k] inside the function and it gets me the value that i want but something must be wrong with the return. I mean they are the columns of the 2d list that i want to update. Mind i'm new to Python, too!

Comment: have you reassigned the return value of `Pr` ? what's happening outside the function

Comment: Do you have the indentation right? It was not ok before your post was edited

Comment: @btloseltwin you should give us all of the parameters you've tested. So we can reproduce the result you got.

Comment: What do you get when you print Pr before the return statement?
anyway if you always get zero I suppose one of the factors `t[i][k]` or `n1[i][k]` is equal  to zero.

Comment: @SpghttCd the identation is right, yes. Graph is a 2d list where each list contains ints, i is an int, candidate_nodes is a list with ints, Pr is a 2d list which i use to give the initial values of the propabilities i want to update and t and n1 are 2d lists with floats. I give as input P=Prop(dist,0,reachable,P,t,n1). I also initialize all elements of P as 0 with P=[[0 for xx in range(len(dist))] for yy in range(len(dist))] . I think there might be a problem with Pr which is the initial matrix that i give as input to the function and i want to update its values but i can't see why.

Comment: @Sharku no, the calculation is right and Pr[i][k] gets the value that must get. Something must be wrong with the "return Pr".

Answer (score 0):

The function should work, as far as I can see. If I throw everything out I do not know about, there are changes to a 2d array full of zeros:

```
def Prop(candidate_nodes, Pr, i):
    pp=0

    for j in candidate_nodes:
          pp+=4*j
    for k in candidate_nodes:
          Pr[i][k]=i/pp
    return Pr

Prop([1,2,3], np.zeros((3,7)), 2)
Out: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```